# How to randomize in pairs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I'm trying to randomize some videos that are both .webm and .mp4.

I have a two of each video for instance vid1.webm and vid1.mp4

I'd like to have the videos randomize and pull both at the same time into the video tag.

safari doesn't support .webm so that's why i would like to have .mp4 as a backup and need both to randomize into the browser on click.

I am loading them from an array and also can't figure out how the folder structure should be listed out, I would really like to keep them in an array as I am loading in several hundred

```
var randomImage = new Array();

randomVideo[0] = "videos/1.webm/ or mp4"; //not sure how to do the file structure
randomVideo[1] = "videos/2.webm/ or mp4"; //
randomVideo[2] = "videos/3.webm/ or mp4"; //

//trying to figure out this part

$(function() {
    $('a.click').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*randomVideo.length);
        $(this).html('<source src="'+randomVideo[number]+'" />');
    });
});

$(function() {
    $('a.click').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*randomVideo.length);
        $(this).html('<source src="'+randomVideo[number]+'" type="video/mp4" /> )
    }
})
```

html

```
<a href="#" class="click">
    <section> 
        <video controls autoplay>
            <script>
               randomVideo()
            </script>
        </video>    
    </section>
</a>
```

If anyone can help me figure this out it would be greatly appreciated!
Can't figure it out, still learning.

Comment: It isn't clear to me what your problem is.  Can't you just have an array of the core video URLs without the extension on them, select a random URL and then add the appropriate extension to it before feeding it to the browser?

Comment: That's not a proper `<img src`. You really want to set the `src` on the video Element. It looks like you'll figure it out now.

Comment: @jfriend00 yeah that would be what I am asking how to do. Except that I would need to randomize the extensions in a pair

Comment: What part do you not know how to do?

Comment: @PHPglue which is best practice? still learning

Comment: Separate all JavaScript to an external `<script src='somewhere.js'></script>`. Use jQuery to select the Video Element if it's already in the DOM. I would give it an HTML `id` attribute, to make your life easy. An array can be made like `var somevar = []` in JavaScript. `RandomImage` and `RandomVideo` are not the same.

Comment: Make an array of your URLs without extension, one URL per video.  Select a random URL from that array.  Determine which browser you have and which extension you need.  Add that extension onto the randomly selected URL and insert it into the web page.  You don't have to deal with pairs at all.

Comment: @jfriend00 you shouldn't need to sniff browser - it will iterate sources and use the first one supported. See my answer below

Comment: @geedubb - then, the OP can just create both URLs, insert both and the browser will pick the one it wants.  The point is that the OP doens't have to select anything in pairs.  They select a random core URL and then construct the pair by adding the extensions to the core.

Comment: @jfriend00 indeed - I agree, as per my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple issues. Firstly your array name doesn't match (randomImage and randomVideo). Not sure why you are hooking the click event twice. One approach is to store the common parts of the path in the array and then concatenate the file ending. Also, I have no idea what you were trying to do with the `img` tag...

Anyway, the code below should help you, if I have understood what you are trying to do correctly.

```
var randomVideo = new Array();
// define your common video paths here
randomVideo[0] = "videos/1";
randomVideo[1] = "videos/2";
randomVideo[2] = "videos/3";

function randomiseVideos() {
        var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomVideo.length);
        $('#myvid').empty(); // clean up from last time
        // now add 2 sources (will fall back appropriately depending on client support)
        $('#myvid').append('<source src="' + randomVideo[number] + '.webm" type="video/webm">');
        $('#myvid').append('<source src="' + randomVideo[number] + '.mp4" type="video/mp4">');
}

$(function () {
    // Randomise on page load
    randomiseVideos();
    // handle click on test link
    $('a.click').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        randomiseVideos();
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="click">Test Link</a>
<section>
    <video id="myvid" width="320" height="240" controls autoplay></video>
</section>
```

**[JS fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LkLojpac/3/)**

Comment: awesome! This looks like it might be what im looking for. 
Quick question but what is the ('#myvid') targeting?

Comment: The video tag in the HTML has `id="myvid"`. So targetting the bare video tag in the markup

Comment: @h0bb5 does that look like what you are after?

Comment: still trying it out as we speak. For some reason on page load no video plays, then when clicked it goes to one video and auto plays and no further clicks work after it. 
There is also no console errors either.

Comment: @h0bb5 by the way the videos wont actually play in my example as the paths are wrong, but you should be able to inspect element to see what's going on under the covers

Comment: Is it because there is no initial randomize on page load? Only when a click occurs it randomizes but then only once and wont randomize on click anymore..

Comment: awh man thanks for all the help =[ wasn't able to get it though. I'll give you the upvote anyways for effort. Tried out your code but for some reason it after it randomizes on load when you click it doesnt click to randomize again. You can essentially only click or randomize the page once instead of being able to click through it. Not sure what is wrong with it

Comment: Which browser are you using? - repeated clicks working on Chrome 39.0.2171.95

Comment: I'm using chrome Version 39.0.2171.95 (64-bit)
I've tried firefox as well.. 
Still working on this today as I haven't been able to get it to work
There are no console errors, and I have the exact code you've put in the jsfiddle so i'm stumped

Answer (score 1):

The video element supports multiple sources https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video

A very simple solution would be to store a list of video objects in your array:

```
var videos = [
    [{type:'mpg', 'src':'blah.mpg'}, {type:'webm', 'src':'blah.webm'}],
    [{type:'mpg', 'src':'blah2.mpg'}, {type:'webm', 'src':'blah2.webm'}],
];

...

var video = videos[randomIndex];
```

And use that to output sources like:

```
<video controls>
  <source src="blah.mpg" type="video/ogg">
  <source src="blah.webm" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the <code>video</code> element.
</video>
```

Comment: this looks interesting but how would the javascript math.rand code come into play with it?

Comment: I guess what i'm asking is how would it know to even randomize with that code?

Comment: randomIndex = parseInt(Math.random()*videos.length);

Comment: I've got it all loading in fine with your code but I can't seem to test it. 
I think the reason is that I do not have the click working to trigger the randomize?

Comment: I think the problem is that after the click occurs it isn't outputting the randomized array into the video tag, how do I do that?